# Bookmark lines that contain percentage values below a certain threshold

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++, I'm seeking assistance to bookmark lines that contain percentage values below a certain threshold. For instance, how can I bookmark all lines featuring percentage values lower than 98.5%?

I tried following regular expressions but I failed:

```
^(?=.*\b(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?|98(?:\.[0-4]\d*)?)%).*$
  
^(?=.*\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,}%.*$).*$
  
^(?=.*\b\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?%.*$)(?!.*\b98\.5%.*$).*$
  
^.*\b(?:98(?:\.[0-4]\d*)?|(?<!\d)9[0-7](?:\.\d*)?)%\b.*$
```

where is my regex problem?

Comment: From 0 to 98.5, without any optimizations, using the regex generator - `\b(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-7])(?:\.\d+)?|98(?:\.[0-5])?)%` - https://regex101.com/r/iW5mZe/1

Comment: @Wiktor - maybe change `[1-8]` to `[0-8]` to allow for 07.3%??

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I doubt that was the problem, but any optimizations are possible and welcome.